# Generating random numbers with a vector of integers as seed in Java

Tags: java, random, numbers, random-seed

I want to generate reproducible random numbers  representing quantities at different points in 3 dimensional space, e.g.

```
double draw = rand(int seed, int x, int y, int z)
```

I want the same inputs to always produce the same draw.  I don’t want to generate all the values in advance as there would be too many.

I want the draws for different positions to be independent.  I also want draws for the same position with different seeds to be independent.  This rules out taking the sum or product of the four arguments, and using this as a seed.

Comment: "I want.."  I want a pony.  Now we're done sharing what we want, did you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
return new Random(seed ^ x ^ y ^ z).nextDouble();
```

(since the seed-argument to the constructor is actually 64 bits, you could get a better "spread" by, say shifting up two of your ints by 32 bits before xor:ing)

---

Another simple solution would be to do something like

```
Random rnd = new Random(seed);
rnd.setSeed(rnd.nextLong() ^ x);
rnd.setSeed(rnd.nextLong() ^ y);
rnd.setSeed(rnd.nextLong() ^ z);
return rnd.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class uses a 48-bit seed that's conveniently divided into three pieces of 16 bits in each, like so.

```
private static long createSeed(long x, long y, long z) {
    return (z & 0xffff) << 32 + (yy & 0xffff) << 16 + (x & 0xffff);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has [Random(long seed)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random(long)) constructor but it takes only a single long value.

But you shouldn't worry much since you can apply a (mathematical) function to your vector and your seed to produce a single number. A poor man's version would be simply adding the numbers:

```
 Random rand = new Random(seed+x+y+z);
```

But as you probably noticed yourself, that isn't the best one as it yields the same result for (1,0,0) and (0,1,0) and (0,0,1). I am sure you can think up a better function instead like `seed + 31*31*x + 31*y + z` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [`setSeed()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#setSeed%28long%29) API, `java.util.Random` uses a 48-bit seed. Your model may suggest the definition of a suitable function to hash your three integer's. Alternatively, you can extend `java.util.Random` with a custom implementation.